# How to convert UTC to local time in a shell script on linux

Tags: linux, shell, date, utc

I have a string of the format

```
20110724T080000Z
```

and I want to convert that to local time in a shell script on linux. I thought I simply could give it as input to date, but I don't seem to be able to tell date what format my input date has.

this

```
date -d "20110724T080000Z" -u
```

would make date complain

```
date: invalid date `20110724T080000Z'
```

Also, what is the format of the form "20110724T080000Z" called? I have had little success trying to google for it.

Comment: Looks like [rfc 3339](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339) format stripped from the punctuation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's [ISO8601 "basic format"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) for a combined date and time. `date` does not seem to be able to parse `20110724T080000Z`, but if you are prepared to do a few string substitutions it parses `20110724 08:00:00Z` correctly.

Answer (score 4):

The `date` program recognizes these 2:
`yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS`
`yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS`

So:

```
a=20110724T080000Z
b=${a:0:4}-${a:4:2}-${a:6:5}:${a:11:2}:${a:13:2}
date +%F_%T -d "${b} +0"
```

Would print `2011-07-24_12:30:00` in my locale.

Comment: date -d "${a:0:-1} UTC"
This removes the last character ("Z") and converts from UTC to locale

Comment: @successfulmike The `date -d "${a:0:-1} UTC"` outputs `date: invalid date ‘20110724T080000 UTC’`. What version of date are you using on what OS? Mine is `date (GNU coreutils) 9.1` on Arch.

Answer (score 1):

its called Zulu time. Its the same as UCT, which used to be referred to as GMT. It's used with the military to specify UCT so there is no confusion on correspondance.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_(Unix)

this command should work according to wikipedia:

date [-u|--utc|--universal] [mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][[.SS]] The only valid option for this form specifies Coordinated Universal Time.

Answer (score 0):

You might try taking advantage of perl:

> perl -e 'print scalar localtime(shift), "\n"' 20110724T080000Z

Though u might have to tweak this a little to get it to work correctly. Ok, I don't know exactly why the perl version doesn't do it well, but here is a Ruby version I've tried, though I can't pick the time out well:

> ruby -e "require 'date';print Date.strptime('20110724T080000Z','%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ').ctime"

gives:

> Sun Jul 24 00:00:00 2011